# Das Verb beschlagnahmen im Kontext

Tags: word-usage

Während ich die Geschichte las, fand ich die Wortkombination schwierig. Hier ist ein Auszug:

> In Südwest damals: da war noch eine [Geliebte]. Ein Hereromädchen. [...]. Mit Brüsten wie Kupfer. Das wird jetzt **beschlagnahmt**. Mit Händen wie Wiese. Und stolzen Knabenfüßen. Und einem Oasenmund.
> [Klabund, Bett Nr. 13]

Wenn ich richtig verstanden habe, waren die Brüste des Mädchens hart wie Kupfer. Oder waren sie mit Kupferringen geschmückt (das sieht man manchmal in Afrika)? Aber dann verwendet der Autor das Verb *beschlagnahmen*  (wegnehmen). Wie verstehen Sie den ganzen Satz? Was wird weggenommen?

Sie können es auf Deutsch schreiben - ich verstehe es. :)

Link zum vollständigen Text:
https://gedichte.xbib.de/kurzgeschichte_Klabund_Bett+Nr.+13.htm

Comment: Ohne die Quelle ist das schwer zu beantworten. *Wie Kupfer* würde ich als Angabe der Farbe verstehen. Menschen werden aber sicher nicht beschlagnahmt und worauf sich *das* bezieht, kann ich nicht erkennen.

Comment: @guidot Im Kontext der Kolonialgeschichte muss man leider davon ausgehen, dass in diesem Text durchaus die Rede davon war, Menschen zu beschlagnahmen. "das" bezieht sich hier auf "das Mädchen"

Comment: @JonathanScholbach Nein, im Kontext des Völkermordes an den Herero ergibt das keinen Sinn - Gefangennahmen waren ausdrücklich untersagt.

Comment: Mir scheint, der Text gibt das Selbstgespräch eines Menschen im Fieber wieder. Das Kupfer lese ich auch eher als Farbe. Aber damals, in Südwest, war dieses Mädchen - beschlagnahmt wird aber irgendwas jetzt, und der Sprecher ist mutmaßlich jetzt schon lange nicht mehr in Namibia (`damals`). Allerdings geht der Text dann wieder mit dem Mädchen weiter. Der ganze Text ist sehr sprunghaft.

Answer (score 6):

"Südwest" ist offensichtlich Namibia, das "Deutsch-Südwestafrika" hieß, solange es eine deutsche Kolonie war (1884–1915). Die Hereros sind ein afrikanisches Volk, das dort lebt.

"Brüste wie Kupfer": ich vermute, dass die Farbe gemeint ist, vielleicht auch dass sie glänzen, jedenfalls bezieht es sich, denke ich, auf das Aussehen, das den Erzähler irgendwie an (eine Statue aus) Kupfer erinnert.

"Das wird jetzt beschlagnahmt": Der Erzähler ist offenbar ein Kolonialherr, vielleicht ein Soldat oder sonst ein Vertreter des deutschen Staates. "Beschlagnahmen" könnte ein sarkastischer Euphemismus für das Entführen des Mädchens wie eine Beute sein. Genau kann man das ohne Kontext nicht sagen.

Comment: "beschlagnahmen" ist mit Sicherheit ein Euphemismus hier. Ich denke allerdings nicht, dass er sarkastisch ist, sondern einfach das de-humanisierende Besitzdenken der Kolonialherren ausdrückt.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach Das Wort "sarkastisch" hatte ich her sicher nicht positiv oder abmildernd gemeint, im Gegenteil. Der Sarkasmus ergibt sich für mich daraus, dass man zu der Zeit (anders als vielleicht 100 Jahre früher) schon genau wußte, dass man einen Menschen nicht "beschlagnahmen" kann, d.h. der Erzähler macht sich hier einen bewussten "Spaß" daraus, es trotzdem so zu nennen.

Answer (score 2):

> Mit Brüsten wie Kupfer.

Wird an dieser Stelle die Farbe der Haut beschrieben?

**Dafür** spricht, dass "kupferfarben" eine zeitgenössisch bekannte Charakterisierung ist. Klabund hat sie an anderer Stelle [selbst verwendet](http://www.gedichte.eu/ex/klabund/der-neger.php). Kinder beschreiben einen schwarzen Sklaven:

> "Seine Stirne edel: wie eine kupferne Schale."

**Dagegen** spricht, dass normalerweise die Hautfarbe der Indianer ("Rothaut") als kupferfarben beschrieben wird. Zudem gibt es später noch eine gegenteilige Beschreibung der Hautfarbe:

> Sie war gar nicht schwarz, sondern kakaobraun.

> Das wird jetzt beschlagnahmt.

Der Erzähler war Soldat in der deutschen Kolonialarmee in Südwestafrika und 1904 am [Völkermord an den Herero](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%B6lkermord_an_den_Herero_und_Nama) beteiligt. Die [bronzene Gedenkmünze](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%BCdwestafrika-Denkm%C3%BCnze) wurde an alle Kämpfer vergeben:

> Schwester! Ich habe Südwest mitgemacht. Ich bin ein Südwest-Afrikaner. Sehen Sie die gelbe Medaille auf meiner Brust?

Dass die "Beschlagnahme" sich auf "das Mädchen" bezieht, ergibt nur Sinn, wenn damit eine Art Gefangennahme oder Versklavung gemeint ist. Das steht jedoch im Widerspruch zu der in Deutschland wohlbekannten und breit diskutierten [Proklamation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%B6lkermord_an_den_Herero_und_Nama#cite_note-41) des Generals von Trotha, die genau das ausschließt:

> Innerhalb der deutschen Grenze wird jeder Herero mit oder ohne Gewehr, mit oder ohne Vieh erschossen, ich nehme keine Weiber und Kinder mehr auf, treibe sie zu ihrem Volk zurück, oder lasse auf sie schießen...
>
> Dieser Erlass ist bei den Appells den Truppen mitzuteilen mit dem Hinzufügen, dass...Schießen auf Weiber und Kinder so zu verstehen ist, dass über sie hinweggeschossen wird, um sie zum Laufen zu zwingen. Ich nehme mit Bestimmtheit an, dass dieser Erlass dazu führen wird keine männlichen Gefangenen zu machen, aber nicht zu Grausamkeit gegen Weiber und Kinder ausartet.

Für den Erzähler sind die Herero Feinde, dennoch liebt er das Mädchen:

> Ich bin dazu verdammt, meine Feinde zu lieben. Meine Feindinnen. (...)
> Wenn ich nur ein Kind von ihr hätte.

Mir will nicht einleuchten wie sich eine "Beschlagnahme" des Mädchens mit dieser Liebeserklärung vereinbaren lässt. Mir erscheint es naheliegender, dass sie sich auf "das Kupfer" bezieht. Dann könnte das Wort in seinem engeren [juristischen Sinne](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beschlagnahme) gemeint sein und einen frei assoziierten Bezug auf die deutsche Kriegswirtschaft in den ersten Jahren des Weltkrieges darstellen.

Insbesondere 1915 musste das Militär seinen Rohstoffbedarf [durch Beschlagnahmen decken](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Wirtschaftsgeschichte_im_Ersten_Weltkrieg#Milit%C3%A4rische_G%C3%BCter), bevor die Kriegswirtschaft in geordnetere Bahnen gelenkt werden konnte. Es wäre nicht die einzige Bezugnahme auf Ereignisse des Jahres 1915 im Text:

> Die Zuckerfabrik von Souchez ... alle Wetter ... alle Himmel ... das war keine Kleinigkeit. Auf der Fabrik möcht ich keine Aktien stehen haben.

Das bezieht sich auf die [Lorettoschlacht](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorettoschlacht), bei der am 11. Mai 1915 die Zuckerfabrik in Souchez [vollständig zerstört](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bundesarchiv_Bild_183-R25767,_Frankreich,_Souchez,_zerst%C3%B6rte_Zuckerfabrik.jpg) wurde.

Comment: Eine Möglichkeit ist, die "Beschlagnahmung" als Vergewaltigung zu lesen. Wenn der Sprecher von "Liebe" und "Geliebte" spricht, würde ich das nicht als Liebeserklärung beschreiben.

Comment: Ich finde deine Vermutung, dass sich "Das wird jetzt beschlagnahmt" grammatisch auf das Kupfer bezieht, überzeugend, das hatte ich vermutlich falsch bezogen. Es löst den Widerspruch zur behaupteten Liebe aber nicht auf. Auch das "Beschlagnahmen des Kupfers" bedeutet ja das Stehlen des Mädchens, oder das "in Beschlag nehmen".  Die Liebeserklärung ist eine nachträgliche, sie widerspricht aus meiner Sicht einer Vergewaltigung nicht. Was das Kind davon gehalten hat, kann man aus dem Text und den historischen Umständen heraus nur vermuten.

Comment: Was man jedoch nicht vermuten muss, ist Klabunds Haltung zu einer Vergewaltigung. In seiner Kurzgeschichte [Der Kinderkreuzzug](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/klabund/erzaehlg/chap004.html), einem Frontalangriff auf das Cristentum, lässt er einen von religiösem Eifer verblendeten Jungen ein neunjähriges Mädchen missbrauchen. Und wenn ich die Balade [Der Neger](http://www.gedichte.eu/ex/klabund/der-neger.php) lese, finde ich vor allem Ehrfurcht vor schwarzer Stärke. SIe passt zu dem Wunsch des Erzählers nach einem "afrikanischen" Sohn...

Comment: ...Klagt Klabund die Haltung des Erzählers also als zynisch an, oder porträtiert er ihn mit seinen eigenen Ansichten? Ich tendiere zum zweiten.

Answer (score -1):

> Wenn ich richtig verstanden habe, waren die Brüste des Mädchens hart wie Kupfer.

Das muß nicht notwendigerweise so sein. Die Brüste werden mit "Kupfer" verglichen, aber ob das Farbe, Konsistenz oder irgendeine andere Eigenschaft betrifft, die die Brüste mit dem Metall gemeinsam haben, geht aus dem Zitat nicht hervor.

> Wie verstehen Sie den ganzen Satz? Was wird weggenommen?

Das einzige, was in dem zitierten Text als Bezug für das Demonstrativpronomen "das" in Frage kommt, ist *das Kupfer*. Inwieweit das allegorisch gemeint ist und (wie @HalvarF vermutet) ein Euphemismus für die Entführung des Mädchens oder wortwörtlich gemeint die Beschlagnahmung von Metallbeständen beschreibt, ist - jedenfalls ohne weiteren Kontext - nicht sicher. Möglich sind sicher auch noch andere Interpretationen.

Es ist generell schwierig, grammatikalische Maßstäbe an einen Text anzulegen, der offensichtlich Grammatik und deren Regeln nicht strikt befolgt. (Gründe dafür zu finden wäre Interpretation und hier off topic.) Jedenfalls ist

> Mit Händen wie Wiese.

und das weitere keineswegs grammatikalisch korrekt - aus welchen Gründen diese Inkorrektheiten erfolgten ist Spekulation, die ich mir hier erspare.

Comment: Der Kontext der nachfolgenden Sätze macht klar, dass es hier um das Mädchen geht, wenn "das wird jetzt beschlagnahmt" gesagt wird.